# What is wrong with the way I have used the limit comparison test to check if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

This problem comes from Example 3, pg. 780, in the 11th edition of Thomas' Calculus.

### The problems asks to check if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}}$ converges. The solution given in the book is as follows:

Because $\ln n$ grows much more slowly than $n^{c}$ for any positive constant $c$, we would expect to have $$  \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}}<\frac{n^{1/4}}{n^{3/2}}=\frac{1}{n^{5/4}} $$ for sufficiently large values of $n$. Indeed, taking $a_{n}=(\ln n)/n^{3/2}$ and $b_{n}=1/n^{5/4}$, we have

\begin{align*}  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln n}{n^{1/4}}\\  &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1/n}{(1/4)n^{-3/4}}\\  &=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4}{n^{1/4}}=0. \end{align*}

Since $\sum b_{n}=\sum (1/n^{5/4})$ (a $p$-series with $p>1$) converges, $\sum a_{n}$ also converges by the Limit Comparison Test.

---

My question is on what basis is the author taking the power of $n$ to be $1/4$ when making the initial comparison of $\ln n < n^{1/4}$? If this $c$ in $n^c$ can be any positive constant, then I can take $c=1/2$ and then show that the series diverges. Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: To show the series diverges you would have to prove the  *reverse* inequality. Do you think you can?

Comment: Comparing $\log(n)$ and $\sqrt{n}$ is not enough to prove convergence. On the other hand you may compare $\frac{\log(n)}{n\sqrt{n}}$ and $\frac{\log(n)}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\log(n+1)}{\sqrt{n+1}}$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $c=1/2$, you'd only get that the series is $\leqslant +\infty$, which is true, but not helpful.

Comment: For $c=1/2$, I have obtained $lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, which should mean that $\sum a_n$ diverges?

Comment: @J.Doe No. If $a_n,b_n > 0$ and $\exists \lim_n \frac{a_n}{b_n}=:c$ with $c \in (0, +\infty)$, then $\sum_n a_n$ and $\sum_n b_n$ are equiconvergent. In your case, $c=0$, so $c \notin (0, +\infty)$, so the limit comparison test is not helpful there. You can take a look at the wikipedia as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn't reading the definitions correctly, and going back I just saw that the case when the limit is $0$ in the comparison test gives us a result when the series $\sum b_n$ is convergent. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

If you take $c=1/2$ you get $$ \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}} < \frac{1}{n}$$
which is not enough to prove that the series diverge; for that you'd need $$ \frac{\ln n}{n^{3/2}} \ge \frac{1}{n}$$
but that's not what you have.

In general, you want to have your series bounded from above by a convergent series (to prove convergence), or bounded by below by a divergent series (to prove divergence). Bounding from above by a divergent series or bounding from below by a convergent series are not enough to establish the convergence of the examined series.

Comment: For $c=1/2$, I have obtained $lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$, which should mean that $\sum a_n$ diverges?

Comment: @J.Doe On what basis do you think that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$ should mean that $\sum a_n$ diverges? Note that if $a_n$ were simply $0$ for all $n$, you'd still have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=0$; would you want to infer that $\sum 0$ diverges?

Comment: Thanks so much. I wasn't reading the definitions correctly, and going back I just saw that the case when the limit is $0$ in the comparison test gives us a result when the series $\sum b_n$ is convergent. Thanks again.